# How to use tf.compute_gradient_error

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to use `tf.test.compute_gradient_error` to check if all gradients are reasonable (almost equal zero).

I did a small test, It seems this function accept placeholder.
Compute gradient error without feed placeholder data is ok

```
x = tf.Variable([2], dtype=tf.float32)
xp = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 5])
y = xp * 2
y2 = y * x
y3 = y2 * 3
y4 = tf.reduce_mean(y3)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    # err = 9.84e-5
    err = tf.test.compute_gradient_error(y2, (2, 5), y3, (2, 5))
    # err1 = 6.94e-5
    err1 = tf.test.compute_gradient_error(y2, (2, 5), y4, ())
```

But when I start check, It shows error message

```
loss_sumup = func(sumup) # e.g. concat and reduce_mean....
loss = loss_sumup + lossL2
# err = 4.67e-5
err = tf.test.compute_gradient_error(loss_sumup, [], loss, [])

# err1: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder'
err1 = tf.test.compute_gradient_error(lossL2, [], loss, [])

# err2: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder'
err2 = tf.test.compute_gradient_error(sumup, [100, 10], loss, [])
```

lossL2 is weight l2 loss

```
tf_vars = tf.trainable_variables()
lossL2 = tf.add_n([tf.nn.l2_loss(v) for v in tf_vars
                   if 'bias' not in v.name]) * 0.001
```

If I use parameter `extra_feed_dict` to feed placeholder data, the pycharm debuger show `Timeout waiting for response on 113`
I think timeout is a acceptable result, because my model use almost 2 mins for each iteraction, I need to find some way to speed up

**Edit 02/11**

```
A = 200
B = 1
# f = np.random.rand(A, B)
# vif = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[A, B])
f = np.ones((A, B), dtype=np.float32)
vif = tf.constant(f, dtype=tf.float32)

out1 = vif + tf.floor(vif)
out2 = tf.sub(vif, tf.floor(vif))
out3 = tf.subtract(vif, tf.floor(vif))
out4 = vif - tf.floor(vif)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # sometimes value close 500, sometimes close 1E-5
    err1 = tf.test.compute_gradient_error(vif, [A, B], out1, [A, B])
    err2 = tf.test.compute_gradient_error(vif, [A, B], out2, [A, B])
    err3 = tf.test.compute_gradient_error(vif, [A, B], out3, [A, B])
    err4 = tf.test.compute_gradient_error(vif, [A, B], out4, [A, B])
```

Comment: `compute_gradient_error` is only intended for testing, and I would expect it to always be far slower than TensorFlow's normal gradient computation. I would suggest using it in unit tests if necessary, but never using it during training/inference.

Comment: Hi @AllenLavoie I add an other test, the result of `gradient_error` is unstable, does it work right?

Comment: `floor` isn't differentiable, so presumably it blocks normal gradient computation and throws off the finite differences method. Not sure there is anything useful it could do here.